# How to do onclick on particular table row in MaterialTable

Tags: reactjs

I have two issues in MaterialTable
* I am using MaterialTable in reactjs , i want to do onClick on particular row . I am passing JSON data in table. How can i implement this?

```
columns: [
        { title: 'Username', field: 'username' },
        { title: 'Team Membership', field: 'teammembership' },

      ],

<MaterialTable   
  title = "Team Members"
  columns={this.state.columns}
  data={this.state.rowData}
/>
```

teammembership should be clickable

*How to add a button in particular row, rather than action? I am already using action in first row , i want to add one button not along with action, but in 3rd row.

```
 columns: [
                { title: 'User Name', field: 'username' },
                { title: 'Role',
                    field: 'roles',
                    lookup: { 34: 'Primary', 63: 'Secondary' ,53 : 'Escallation', 54:'Override ' },
                  },

                { title: 'Start Date', field: 'Startdate', type: 'datetime' },
                { title: 'End Date', field: 'enddate', type: 'datetime' },

                {title : 'Repeat', field:'repeat'},

              ],
              data: [
                { username: 'Mehmet', roles: '34', Startdate: 1987, enddate: 2018,repeat:'repeat' },
                {
                  username: 'Zerya Betül',
                  roles: '63',
                  Startdate: 2017,
                  enddate: 2019,
                  repeat:'repeat'
                },
              ],

 <MaterialTable   
       title = ""
       columns={this.state.columns}
       data={ this.state.data}

       editable={{
          onRowAdd: newData =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
             resolve();
             const data = [...this.state.data];
             data.push(newData);
             setState({ ...this.state, data });
          }, 600);
                              }),
                            onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                              new Promise(resolve => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                  resolve();
                                  const data = [...this.state.data];
                                  data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                                  setState({ ...this.state, data });
                                }, 600);
                              }),
                            onRowDelete: oldData =>
                              new Promise(resolve => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                  resolve();
                                  const data = [...this.state.data];
                                  data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                                  setState({ ...this.state, data });
                                }, 600);
                            }),

                          }}

                    />
```

in the place of repeat i want to place a button

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The  component has an onRowClick prop which can be used to have things happen onClick of a given row. Please see the documentation [here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/detail-panel) and look specifically at the section "Detail Panel With RowClick Example".

Comment: I tried onRowClick and things only happen when you click on a table row not when you make a selection from the lookup. I have tried onSelectedChange lots of stuff nothing fires when I make a selection from my lookup.

Comment: I have went through that documentation over and over I am using the editable but that only fires when I add, update, delete I need it to fire when I make a certain selection. This seems to be straightforward. I should be able to have a function add state when something is selected.